# On the menu: Jobs offered!

Tags: discussion

Jobs? As in "Home, Questions, Tags, Users, Jobs, Unanswered" in the menu to the left.

How do we feel about that?

Comment: See [Jobs on Technical Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349271/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Huh, I saw this meta post earlier, but I thought it wouldn't apply to [cs.se], since we are in the "Science" category, rather than the "Technology" category. (Not that I'd expected these categories to mean much...)

Comment: Indeed, those jobs would be "off-topic" here. Also the totally strange placement of the link: somewhare in the cs-site navigation. As stupid as a Youtube advertisment in the middle of a long song.

Comment: Agreed. Even assuming best intentions, this link seems like major YAGNI.

Comment: These are indeed YAGNI, but assumed nothing we can do about it, or can we?